# See goal conversion for before I created the goal?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking

I just created a [Goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040) in Google Analytics.
The goal creation/admin page shows:

> This Goal would have a 35.71% conversion rate based on your data from the past 7 days.

[image: goal]

---

## Problem:

Despite what "verify" said above, Analytics shows me 0% conversions for the past:

[image: goal zero]

---

## Question:

Is there any way to make my goal retroactive?
Google has all the data, so I guess it is possible somehow?

Comment: Just a note about your setup, you don't need to include the hostname for your goal. It should simply be, in your case, /web/guest/page2. Since you are using "Equals to", make sure you have name that path/file exactly, so if it's an html page, you should put in /web/guest/page2.html (just follow the example they give right beneath the field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation conversion rate is just a "prediction", but when you see you actual conversion rate it is 0 because the goal hasn't taken effect yet. You will need to wait a day for conversion rates to be non-zero, assuming you get actual conversion until then. Goals are not retroactive either.

Comment: Not retroactive... that's what I was afraid about. Thanks for the tip too!